# Cannot cast object in Jenkins job generator

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a problem with my DSL job generator:

```
Processing DSL script seed.groovy
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.connection.GitLabApiTokenImpl@4046fd60' with class 'com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.connection.GitLabApiTokenImpl' to class 'com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.connection.GitLabApiTokenImpl'
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:405)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:232)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:603)
at com.blue.devops.generator.Generator$_closure1.doCall(Generator.groovy:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I am running a DSL job generator that access gitswarm API, gets the information about available projects and their branches and creates Jenkins jobs.

Interaction with gitswarm api is done via Client class - my gitswarm API client.

Generator.groovy:

```
class Generator {

SystemCredentialsProvider systemCredentialsProvider = (SystemCredentialsProvider) Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList('com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider')[0]
CredentialsStore credentialsStore = (CredentialsStore) systemCredentialsProvider.getStore()
Domain domain = Domain.global()
List<Credentials> credentials = credentialsStore.getCredentials(domain)

Client client

Generator(String tokenId="gitswarm_token") {
    credentials.each { Credentials credentials ->
        if(credentials.getId() == tokenId) {
            GitLabApiTokenImpl token = (GitLabApiTokenImpl) credentials //line 28
            client = new Client(apiToken: token.getApiToken().getPlainText())
        }
    }
}

boolean generateJobs(DslFactory factory) {
    ArrayList<Project> supportedProjects = client.getSupportedProjects()
    supportedProjects.each { supportedProject ->
        handleProject(supportedProject, factory)
    }
    return true
}
}
```

Jenkins is running this DSL seed job:

```
import com.blue.devops.generator.Generator
new Generator().generateJobs(this)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The Job DSL classloader does not support access to classes provided by other plugins. So you can't import a class from another plugin and can't cast an object to that class.

But Groovy is a dynamic language. You don't need to cast an object to a specific class to be able to access it's members. Groovy will figure that out at runtime. The following example show how to get the API token with using any classes from plugins.

```
def systemCredentialsProvider = Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList('com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider')[0]
def credentials = systemCredentialsProvider.credentials
def gitlabCredentials = credentials.find { it.id == 'test' }
def apiToken = gitlabCredentials.apiToken.plainText
```

Comment: thanks :) We figured out that is the classloader issue. I solved it so that I would not need to access classes provided by other plugins.